# Get all pages API

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics

I am working on a project that we need to retrieve all the unique visitors for each page in Google Analytics.

It is possible to see all the pages in one website and get the information for each page in the Google Analytics. However I could not find the Rest API for get all the pages or visitors for each page.

The final goal is that we need to have a drop box which shows all the pages/urls and after we select one of them it shows the number of the visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) to extract the data on all the pages.  You should start by checking out the [Page Tracking dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking).

Once you have the page you want you can [filter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#dimensionfilterclause) additional requests to get additional data for each of the pages.

Tip: Look into the [Google javascript client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js).

Comment: Takk skal du ha